# How do I use wp_dropdown_pages in Wordpress to show only certain pages?

Tags: php, wordpress, menu

I'm new to Wordpress and I need to make a dropdown box with a submit button that takes me to four certain pages. I have the php code

```
<li id="pages">
<h2><?php _e('pages:'); ?></h2>
<form action="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>" method="get">
<?php wp_dropdown_pages(); ?>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="view" />
</form>
</li>
```

To give me the options for all pages but I can't seem to find a way to only show the pages I want. Do I have to make a custom menu? Hope someone can guide me in the right direction, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`wp_dropdown_pages()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_dropdown_pages/) uses the [`get_pages()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_pages/) function; hence, you can use any parameters available for the `get_pages()` function, which in your case would be the `include` param.

So here's an example:

```
<?php wp_dropdown_pages( array(
  'include' => array( 1, 2, 3 ), // Array of page IDs to include.
) ); ?>
```